# Configuring PyCharm for QGIS in OS X?

Tags: pyqgis, installation, osx, pycharm

Can anyone point me to instructions for setting up PyCharm (or any IDE) on OS X to run QGIS for building standalone scripts/applications?

I have seen many tutorials for Windows, but nothing out there (that I can find) for OS X.